# Django : how to upload a file in admin

Tags: django, admin, filefield

I try to create a link to download a file in the admin but it does not work

my model

```
class Event(models.Model):
    ......
    file = models.FileField(_('fichier'), upload_to='medias',  null=True,  blank=True)

    def file_(self):
        if self.file:
            return "<a href='%s'>download</a>" % (self.file.url,)
        else:
            return "No attachment"
```

my admin :

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

list_display = ('title', 'start', 'end', 'user', 'fin', 'frequency', 'file_',)


fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'fields': ('title','start', 'end', 'is_cancelled', 'calendar', 'user', 'description', ('frequency', 'fin' ), 'activated', 'file_',)
    }),
```

I get the error :

> Exception Value:
>
> 'EventAdmin.fieldsets[0][1]['fields']' refers to field 'file_' that is
>   missing from the form.

what is this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your admin like this:

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('title', 'start', 'end', 'user', 'fin', 'frequency', 'file_link',)


    fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'fields': ('title','start', 'end', 'is_cancelled', 'calendar', 'user', 'description', ('frequency', 'fin' ), 'activated', 'file',)
    }),

    def file_link(self, obj):
        if obj.file:
            return "<a href='%s'>download</a>" % (obj.file.url,)
        else:
            return "No attachment"
```

Answer (score 0):

`file_` is a function in your model. You can only show fields in a fieldset. A valid field would be `file` itself, but not the function `file_`.

I would also construct the HTML in your template and not in your model (I am not even sure if this is working what you have done so far).

Assuming you pass the object `event` with your view to your template. So you can use in your HTML template file:

```
{% if event.file %}
    <a href="{{ event.file.url }}">Download</a>
{% else %}
    No attachment
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I want to open the file only in the admin, not in a template

Comment: Oh okay, sorry, didn't know that. But one of your errors is caused by `file_` which is not a field but a function.